# How to play an Exclamation or Asterisk sound in the .NET Compact Framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, c#-2.0

I want to create audible feedback to the user to signal success or failure of data validation. Playing the *system* Asterisk and Exclamation sounds seem to be the proper way to do this, especially since the device may have non-standard sounds configured.

The problem is that System.Media is not available in the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 to play them.

What alternative ways do I have to play these system sounds?

Comment: Can you install CF 3.5 on the device?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport(”winmm.dll”)]

private static extern bool PlaySound( string filename, int module, int flags );

PlaySound(Application.StartupPath + "/test.wav",0,SND_ASYNC);
```

There is a whole article on this [here](http://www.davidjsushil.com/tutorials/winapisounds.pdf)

Comment: Seems to be in CF 3.5, bad luck I guess :X

Answer (score 0):

I've been down this road.  The [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909766.aspx) API (which uses CoreDll.DLL acutally) is about the only option you have.

I had a static class for this, but the results weren't loud enough and ended replacing it with code that used the Symbol.Audio classes (symbol bar code scanner).